# How to Set up Bootstrap 4.5 on Git Pages

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, github-pages

What is a good way to set up Bootstrap 4.5 on a website hosted as a Github Page?

Most of the Bootstrap 4.5 files such as the CSS and JS folders transfer fine to github. However, Bootstrap 4.5 includes Sass which comes with the Node Modules folder.  The Node Modules folder is loaded with many files, too many for github to accept at once (github presents an error that it will not accept so many files, must be less than 100). It seems silly to break up the folder into packets less than 100 files each. I imagine there is a much better way which I am unaware of.

Comment: You don't check node modules into git, put your package json file into git. And everyone who wants to develop has to do mom install

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.

If you want to upload files upto 100MB, you can use for example command line.
If you have more than 100 files, there are a few  ways to upload.

One of the ways is to create a clone of your repository on the local machine.

I used to use GitHub Desktop

As an alternative to Github Desktop, you can also use SourceTree.

Answer (score 0):

In the view of being helpful, I have to say that it is not actually necessary to upload the node modules to your server which in this case is hosted on Git Pages. The server only needs your html files, your CSS files (which as you have pointed out are compiled from SCSS), and any other special content such as images and SVGs.

It is true that when working with the SCSS from Bootstrap 4.5 it gives a node modules folder, but once you compile your SCSS into a CSS file, then all you need to do is upload the single CSS file to your server.

Although it may appear I have not addressed your question, in fact the above answer removes the need to upload all those files in the first place.